# NSArray from SQLite to draw CGRects

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, cgrect

I'm hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction.  I'm new to iOS/Objective C, but familiar with classic ASP/PHP.

I'm trying to dynamically generate CGRects (filled ellipses) using data from an SQLite database.  I am able to connect to the SQLite database and pull an array, so that's working.  You'll see that I have my CGRect goal successfully writing to the NSLog, along with manually drawing two dots.

I just need a little push in the right direction as far as the best method to place items from the "record set" into the CGRect line, in a similar method to how I have it sent to the NSLog.

My working CGRect code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Set dot alpha transparency
CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.70);

// And draw with a blue fill color
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

// Fill rect convenience equivalent to AddEllipseInRect(); FillPath();
int ellipseDiameter = 35.0;
int drawOffset = ellipseDiameter / 2;

//NSArray into NSLog showing how CGRect should be formatted from SQLite data
NSArray *locationInfos = [LocationDatabase database].locationInfos;
for (LocationInfo *info in locationInfos) {
    NSLog(@"CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(%@ - drawOffset, %@ - drawOffset, ellipseDiameter,ellipseDiameter))", info.xCoordText, info.yCoordText);
}

//drawing dot 1 
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(125.0 - drawOffset, 108.0 - drawOffset, ellipseDiameter, ellipseDiameter));

//drawing dot 2
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(132.0 - drawOffset, 146.0 - drawOffset, ellipseDiameter, ellipseDiameter));    
}
```

Any direction would really be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`info.xCoordText` and `info.yCoordText` are `NSString`, just call `[info.xCoordText floatValue]` to turn them into floats.

i.e.:

```
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(info.xCoordText.floatValue - drawOffset, info.yCoordText.floatValue - drawOffset, ellipseDiameter,ellipseDiameter));
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed!  Thank you.  I take it that the floatValues are similar to recordsets... this makes my life so much easier.  Thanks again!